# Storm jar command fails with NoClassDefFound error although jar is present in the dependency. Able to run the project with Eclipse though

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, apache-storm

I am new to java and storm and am trying to run a project in storm local cluster. topology runner and bolt are present in 1st project and spout is present in 2nd project. the jar of 2nd project is present in the pom of 1st project as dependency and it works correctly in eclipse. However when i try to package the 1st project and execute the storm jar command on 1st project jar it gives NoClassDefFound error on spout class. can't figure out the reason. Any help would be appreciated.

**My error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: nl/minvenj/nfi/storm/kafka/KafkaSpout
at com.wincere.lamda.storm.TopologyRunner.main(TopologyRunner.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.minvenj.nfi.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout**
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 1 more
```

My Pom File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-         4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>storm_separate</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>storm_separate</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>



<repositories> 
  <repository> 
    <id>clojars.org</id> 
    <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url> 
  </repository> 
</repositories> 


<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>




 <dependency>
    <groupId>nl.minvenj.nfi.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-spout</artifactId>
    <version>0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${projectdir}/lib/kafka-spout-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>vertica</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertica-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
 </dependency>



 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.yammer.metrics</groupId>
    <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
 </dependency>



</dependencies>



</project>
```

projectdir is correctly specified.

i am using storm 0.9.2 incubating to create storm cluster on my machine

Comment: Can you give the command "java etc..." used by storm jar? It should show itself in the shell when you launch. Probably classpath problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However I already found out the mistake. I was not using jar with dependency file instead was working on simple jar. All that was required was plugin to create jar with dependency.